# How to make an automatic redirect in html/js that takes you to a random website in an array?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<h1>heelo</h1>
<script type ="text/javascript">
   //this all should redirect but does not
   alert('You are being redirected to random website')                            
   var responses = ["https://www.google.com",    "https://www.youtube.com"]
   var rand =  responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)];
   window.location.replace(`${rand}`)
  }
```

Comment: That code looks incomplete. Which errors are you getting?

Comment: Need to close that script tag and remove the extra `}` at end. use your browser console to check errors

Comment: you probably want `window.location.href = rand`

Answer (score 1):

I changed the way the JavaScript variable is provided to [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace).
It's simply `rand` rather than `` `${rand}` ``.

I also removed the unmatched closing `}` and added the matching closing `</script>`.

```
<h1>heelo</h1>
<script type ="text/javascript">
   alert('You are being redirected to random website')                            
   var responses = ["https://www.google.com",    "https://www.youtube.com"]
   var rand =  responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)];
   window.location.replace(rand)
</script>
```